# Convert blob to Django ImageField in python?

Tags: python, django, django-models, blob

I read user image in BLOB file, but i want save it to image format in django model.
How can i convert this file to image file(.jpeg) and save it in django models.ImageField?
I use python 2.7 and django 1.9.
my model is:

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    cn =  models.CharField(max_length=100)

    new_comer = models.NullBooleanField()
    change_position = models.NullBooleanField()
    change_manager = models.NullBooleanField()
    acting = models.NullBooleanField()
    expelled = models.NullBooleanField()
    active = models.NullBooleanField()
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='/images/')
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You need to try something like this.

```
import io
from django.core.files.base import File

# Set values of your model filed.
staff_instance = Staff()
staff_instance.user = user_instance
...
...

with io.BytesIO(blob_file) as stream:
    django_file = File(stream)
    staff_instance.avatar.save(some_file_name, django_file)

staff_instance.save()
```

I assume that blob is a byte array of the file. 
To make it a file i need to convert it to a stream.
Thus I thought `BytesIO` would be a good choice.

You can directly save file to disk but if you want django to upload it to your `upload_to` directory, you need to use `django.core.files.base.File` class.
When you run `django.core.files.base()` method file will be saved to desired directory.

> I guess you will use this for an data migration process, not in a view. 
>   If this is the case than you could put this code at a [django command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/). 
>   Then you can use any django and project related resources.

Let me know if it helps.